# How do I make a transition between two states to be slowly?

Tags: unity

Now it's doing the first New State then it's jumping to New State 0
Instead I want it to slowly move between the two states. I want to see the animation transition slowly changing from state to state.

For example when you see a character sitting and then standing so to see the transition from sitting to standing slow.

[image: Transition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You need an intermediate state

And play an animation that when completed, sets the character to the resulting state.

Comment: I found that if I change the duration time in the Inspector drag it much to the right it does the slow motion effect between the states. Is that wrong way to do it ?

Comment: @BenziAvrumi That might work too, I'm not that familiar with the animation system.